# What does this function gives count(preceding-sibling::*) + 1?

Tags: xml, xpath, xsd, crystal-reports, xpath-2.0

count(preceding-sibling::*) + 1 is the condition which has been given in my source field. I want to know what value it returns. It would be great if someone could explain each function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It returns the count of the preceding sibling elements of the selected element + 1.

For example:

```
<root>
  <element/>
  <element/>
  <element/>
</root>
```

When the context node is the last `element`, it will return 3.

Answer (score 2):

Which part of it don't you understand?

- preceding-sibling returns the nodes having the same parent as the
  context node, that come before the context node in document order.
- ::* selects those preceding sibling nodes that are elements.
- count() tells you how many nodes are selected by the argument
  expression
- +1 adds one.

I'm afraid if there are concepts there that you don't understand, like "context node" or "node" or "element" or "parent", then you need to do more reading.

Comment: Thanks Michael. I am new to Xpath and i am still learning. Thanks for clarifying my doubt.